# Does anyone want to work on merging AR9285 questions?

Tags: discussion

On [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286324/ar9285-wireless-network-problem-ubuntu-13-04) someone responded with "There are about 100 posts on this particular wireless device on here.", and I thought, that sucks and did a search and there are a bunch.

Does anyone want to tackle merging these so we don't have stuff everywhere like we've done for the broadcom questions? Preferably someone who actually owns this card? I'd be willing to toss in a huge bounty if someone is looking for motivation. :)

Comment: Here's also the [search for AR29285 questions](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3A0+AR9285).